# "Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed."

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

First, here is block of code and the LogCat below.  Notice the line of the crash.

```
if (!database.isOpen()) {
    open();
}

Cursor c = database.rawQuery(check_for_special, new String[]{String.valueOf(debt_id), sMonth});
if (c.getCount() == 0) { // LINE OF CRASH HERE
    c.close();
    return BigDecimal.ZERO;
} else {
    c.moveToFirst();
    BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("payment")));
    c.close();
    return amount;
}
```

LogCat:

```
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318): Process: com.kickinglettuce.debtplannerpro, PID: 14318
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because the connection pool has been closed.
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.throwIfClosedLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:962)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.waitForConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:599)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.acquireConnection(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:348)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.acquireConnection(SQLiteSession.java:894)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:834)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:144)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at com.---.---.DebtDataSource.getSpecialPayment(DebtDataSource.java:1389)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at com.---.---.DebtDataSource.payoffDebt(DebtDataSource.java:687)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at com.---.---.PlannerFragment$PlannerTask.doInBackground(PlannerFragment.java:181)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at com.---.---.PlannerFragment$PlannerTask.doInBackground(PlannerFragment.java:145)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-02 12:33:29.539: E/AndroidRuntime(14318):    ... 4 more
```

I am not understanding this error.  I read in many places that you could remove the `close()` call but that does not help.  Especially since it crashes before that.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Just a guess. Is your displayed method or method `open()` synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when the database is already closed. Seeing your first line in the pasted code `if (!database.isOpen()) {` makes me think you have `database.close()` somewhere else. If that's the case just remove it and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Move the moveToFirst method to before the getCount method.

Comment: So when I do this, I know get the same error on the `moveToFirst()` method.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Is it? That is interesting. For me that was a solution when I faced the same issue. In that case I would say look at your open method to, and see if you opened the database properly